# What is the point of using do-while loop in this code snippet?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, do-while

I was just discovering the `Roslyn` source code and I saw a code snippet looks like this:

```
var text = stringBuilder.ToString();
int length;
do
{
    length = text.Length;
    text = text.Replace("{\r\n\r\n", "{\r\n");
} while (text.Length != length);
```

It looks *odd* to me because the [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, replaces all the occurrences of specified string with a new value in one time.So this loop is executing for first time, perform the changes then executing again for second time and do **nothing**. Then it ends.. So what is the point of using a `loop` instead of just write:

```
var text =  stringBuilder.ToString();
text = text.Replace("{\r\n\r\n", "{\r\n");
```

Or even shorter:

```
var text = stringBuilder.ToString().Replace("{\r\n\r\n", "{\r\n");
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes - you're missing that the string could contain more than two linebreaks after the bracket "{" - it would then continue to delete the additional linebreaks until only one remains.

Comment: I don't really like that code as it is difficult to understand. Of course, it may be a bit faster, but why not use String.Contains("{\r\n")? I don't know where exactly this snippet is used and how long the input is, but normally this would not speed down the program noticably.

Comment: @user2241553: What exactly would you want to achieve with `String.Contains("{\r\n")`?

Comment: I don't think it's that hard to understand, and a single comment would have made it perfectly clear. Plus, for most string libraries (and strings in C#) String.Length is O(1) and String.Contains is O(n). Of course, you could do the entire replacement in a single pass using regular expressions, but...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose the string has three blank lines after an open brace:

```
"{\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

The first iteration would produce this:

```
"{\r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

The second would produce this:

```
"{\r\n\r\n"
```

And the third would produce:

```
"{\r\n"
```

Each iteration removes a single blank line.

Comment: A much more expressive version of my answer.

Comment: that does make sense.I can't believe I miss that :) I will accept this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you're missing that the string could contain more than two linebreaks after the bracket "{" - it would then continue to delete the additional linebreaks until only one remains.

Answer (score 2):

It's using recursion (of a sort) to handle one set of replacements exposing a new set characters that subsequently need replacing in the same way.